# Is there a way to see effects or boost in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Say I drink fortify enchanting or wear certain armor.

I want to know if my enchanting skills have gone up.

I think there is a way to do that. I saw it on the right side of the screen. I just totally forgot how to access that.

I don't want to use a command line or cheat or hack or mod.

Comment: There is a similar question like this with no answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you open your game menu and select the Magic sub-menu you can find an "Active Effects" tab in the list. This page will show you what effects your character is experiencing, including potion bonuses, enchanted armor or divine blessings.

You can read more about Active Effects by visiting this wikia page: https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Active_Effect